# How to make the correct regular expression with hexadecimal value?

Tags: python

I am focusing on data with a regular expression. I am using python and I implement this function:

```
import re
exp = r"\bTimestamp\s+([0-9]+)\s+ID=(\w{32})0*\s+Dest_ID=(\w{32})0*\sASN_Received\s+(?!0000)[0-9A-F]{4}+"
rx = re.compile(exp)
m=rx.match("Timestamp 1549035123  ID=02141592cc0000000300000000000000 Dest_ID=00000000000000000000000000000000 Nbr_Received = ec30000000")
m.groups()
print(m.groups())
```

But it does not work correctly:

I expect to have  this result:

```
('1549033267', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000','00000000000000000000000000000000','ec30000000')
```

Then I want to convert the hexadecimal value to decimal by using this function:

```
def Convert_Decimal(nbr_hex):
nbr_dec = nbr_hex[5] + nbr_hex[2:4] + nbr_hex[0:2]
reversed = int(nbr_dec, 16)
print(reversed)
```

As finalresult I want to have:

```
('1549033267', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000','00000000000000000000000000000000','12524')
```

Comment: Your `exp` value currently produces a `re.error: multiple repeat at position 95` exception.

Comment: Why the negative look-behind for the `Nbr_Received` number, and why not use proper `bytes.as_int()` or `struct()` unpacking for that value, to control byte order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hexadecimal values use the digits 0-9 and the letters A through to F (upper or lowercase), only, and in your case are of a fixed length, so `[0-9a-fA-F]{32}` suffices to match those values. You don't need to match trailing zeros, when you have a fixed-length value.

You really don't want to use `\w` here, you wouldn't want to match underscores, the rest of the English alphabet, or any other letter-like symbol in the Unicode standard (there are thousands).

Next, you are looking for `ASN_Received`, but your input string uses the text `Nbr_Received =` with whitespace around the `=` character. Account for that:

```
exp = (
    r'\bTimestamp\s+([0-9]+)\s+'
    r'ID=([0-9a-fA-F]{32})\s+'
    r'Dest_ID=([0-9a-fA-F]{32})\s+'
    r'Nbr_Received\s*=\s*([0-9a-fA-F]{4,})'
)
```

I broke the expression across multiple lines to be easier to follow. Note that I used `{4,}` for the last hexadecimal value, matching 4 *or more* digits. You can't use `+` and `{n,m}` patterns together, choose one or the other.

You then get:

```
>>> import re
>>> exp = (
...     r'\bTimestamp\s+([0-9]+)\s+'
...     r'ID=([0-9a-fA-F]{32})\s+'
...     r'Dest_ID=([0-9a-fA-F]{32})\s+'
...     r'Nbr_Received\s*=\s*([0-9a-fA-F]{4,})'
... )
>>> rx = re.compile(exp)
>>> m = rx.match("Timestamp 1549035123  ID=02141592cc0000000300000000000000 Dest_ID=00000000000000000000000000000000 Nbr_Received = ec30000000")
>>> print(m.groups())
('1549035123', '02141592cc0000000300000000000000', '00000000000000000000000000000000', 'ec30000000')
```

Also see [this online demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SjxtaF/1/), which explains each part of the pattern on the right-hand side.

I'd convert the last hexadecimal number via [`bytes.fromhex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex) and [`int.from_bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes) to an integer:

```
>>> m.group(4)
'ec30000000'
>>> bytes.fromhex(m.group(4))
b'\xec0\x00\x00\x00'
>>> int.from_bytes(bytes.fromhex(m.group(4)), 'little')
12524
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "Timestamp 1549035123  ID=02141592cc0000000300000000000000 Dest_ID=00000000000000000000000000000000 Nbr_Received = ec30000000"
>>> pat = r'Timestamp\s+(\d+)\s+ID=(\w+)\s+Dest_ID=(\d+)\s+Nbr_Received\s+?=\s+?(\w+)'
>>> re.findall(pat, string)
[('1549035123', '02141592cc0000000300000000000000', '00000000000000000000000000000000', 'ec30000000')]
```

Comment: You really should include an explanation as to why the OP should *try this*. Your pattern matches more than just hexadecimal digits, `\w` is really way too broad. The non-greedy classifiers on the `\s+` brackets are really not needed, as these are always followed by non-space characters. There is no risk of those patterns running away. You didn't address the hex-to-decimal portion of the question, either.

Comment: Okay. The pattern seemed so stable.